# Block certain words and bad language in a webpage and remove the text that is not related to the subject matter of the page

Tags: windows, open-source, firefox

I have 3 questions:

1. On some webpages, even on popular sites, sometimes bad words come up, how to block them?
2. And also, on some webpages, even on popular sites, sometimes such language is written that does not contain bad word(s) but the language is such that makes impact like bad words. So, how to block that language or how to convert it to a polite and gentle form?
3. When viewing a webpage, then how to remove information, that's not related to the subject matter, and only display the main information?

I prefer a solution that is in the form of a software or a browser extension to solve the above three problems. And I prefer Open source software and open source browser extensions more, and please cite sources for any info. I use win. 10 and have Firefox browser.

A basic feature in the software or browser extension should be that the user should be able to add, delete, and edit the list of words and phrases that are to be blocked (this feature can be helpful in solving the 1st problem written above). However, this does not mean that other features are not wanted that are required to solve all the 3 problems above.

Comment: Removing offensive words is a problem as there is no universal definition of offensive, images of such words is more so, and phrases that do not contain any single offensive word but manage to give the same impression are almost impossible to detect automatically.

Comment: Should we block the word `Tump` because it contains the mildly offensive `rump`?  One man's Mede is another man's Perisan :-)

Comment: @SteveBarnes What I mean by offensive is, those words that are blocked, hidden, or masked using asterisks on some websites(by the websites themselves). However, if on any site on which they are not blocked, hidden, or masked, then the software or the browser extension should be able to do it(if there's one).
[Question]. If some websites are able to block, hide, or mask them, then how they are able to do it? And, if they are able to do it automatically, then how can I do it?

Comment: @SteveBarnes (part of the previous comment)

[Question]. And, is there no such software or browser extension that blocks the bad language that is giving the same bad impression without the bad words or convert it into a gentle and polite form?

[Question]. And could you suggest some software or browser extension for my third question also?

Comment: @Mawg In the example that you gave, the word can be blocked if it has no appropriate polite synonym. And the language should be translated.

Comment: @user39803 - You have defined what you need happen to "Offensive" words & phrases but not defined how to define what you find offensive - e.g. Some would find offensive (and others not) the phrase "Donald Trump is a great man!" Certain anatomical names are often found offensive when used in some ways while the medical profession regards them as simple nouns. My point is there is no  universal definition of "Offensive" - note that some find the idea of filtering what people can read highly offensive in itself.

Comment: @SteveBarnes As I have written in my previous comments about what is offensive according to me, “What I mean by offensive is, those words that are blocked, hidden, or masked using asterisks...” (in the case if they are not blocked, hidden, or masked and keep on displaying). And the example phrase that you gave, it is not offensive as it doesn't contain any bad words or make that impact. And regarding the anatomical names, if the site is related to medical study, that's a different thing. And regarding the definition of what is offensive, if the software or browser extension... (continued)

Comment: @SteveBarnes (next part)... allows the user to define [and edit also] their list of words, then the user can add what they find offensive in that list.

Comment: @user39803 - I suggest that you add the facility for the user specify offensive words & phases to your list of required features. However this will still leave the problem of authors bypassing by paraphrasing, e.g. if Cheese is in the list of offensive words the user may still see "set matured milk products", cheddar, etc.

Comment: @SteveBarnes yes, that was required from the beginning, I can use the list where the user specifies the list of offensive words and phrases to be removed, but the question is that I haven't got a hint about a software or a browser extension. And regarding the authors bypassing it by paraphrasing, that similar thing I asked in my question above in point no. 2.

Comment: @SteveBarnes you have given great information but you have not hinted at the names of the possible opensource softwares or opensource browser extensions that can be helpful in solving the 3 problems that I asked in my question. So, could you provide names of any such software or browser extension. kindly reply to this comment, if no also.

Comment: @user39803 I suggest that you edit your question to include this "required from the beginning" feature. I have been trying to make you aware of why your question as asked is unlikely to be able to be answered.

Comment: @SteveBarnes As you suggested, I have edited my question to include the feature. And, if my question is now clear, then could you provide the names of some opensource softwares and some opensource browser extensions to solve the three problems above?

Comment: "remove the text that is not related to the subject matter of the page" is going to require some powerful AI

Comment: @Mawg which software has this feature or how to implement the AI?

Comment: does anyone know about a software solution or a browser extension to solve the problems listed in the question?